# Magento minicart showing empty values

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on magento 1.9 version and some of my website page (inner pages) showing mini cart empty but its working on cart page.

I found a file where it is fetching mini cart values
`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();` 
It is returning blank values.
Please Guide.

Comment: Its working fine on my local machine. this problem come on my server website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when we have `full page cache`.If full page cache is enabled then disable it.

OR

First thing is, Go to admin: `System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart Side Bar. Check Maximum Display Recently Added Item(`s) and set it's value.

If it's not working, then you should debug this file: `\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\cart\minicart\items.phtml`. Do some echo and exit; there